# How to delete some plots in the matplotlib 3D?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have some functions for plotting, but I like that when I call the third function, the plot of the first one disappears. Is this possible? I tried axes.clear (), but it erases everything

The code is divided into several files, but here are the functions of which I speak

```
def pontos(self, nos, ident):  #first function      
    for i in nos:
        self.ax.plot([i[0]], [i[1]], [i[2]], marker = 'o', color = 'black', markersize = 5 )

def barras(self, nos, icd, ident2, rot):#second function
     for i in icd:
         self.ax.plot([nos[i[0]][0],nos[i[1]][0]], [nos[i[0]][1],nos[i[1]][1]], [nos[i[0]][2],nos[i[1]][2]],linewidth=3.5, c='gray')

def deslocamentP(self, deslocamentos, nos, quant): third function
     self.oontos.remove()) ### doens't work ('function' object has no attribute 'remove')
     text = str(deslocamentos[i][0]) + 'm'                    
     self.ax.text((nos[i][0]-0.5), nos[i][1], nos[i][2], text) 
     self.ax.quiver(nos[i][0], nos[i][1], nos[i][2], 1, 0, 0, length = self.scal, color = 'k')
```

Comment: You cannot remove a function. `remove()` is an attribute of the artist. So if you created a plot via `line, = ax.plot(...)` you can remove that line with `line.remove()`.